# Electric potential : numerical value for the triple Integral

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, mathematical-physics, numerical-calculus, electromagnetism

The function $\phi:L\to\mathbb{R}$ where $L={\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:x^2+y^2=4\}}$ is defined as,

\begin{align*}&\phi(x,y)=\\
&\int_{0}^{\pi}\!\!\!\!\int_{0}^{2\pi}\!\!\!\!\int_{1}^{2}\!\!\frac{\cos^2(\Psi) \sin(\theta)}{r^2\sqrt{(x-r\cos(\Psi)\sin(\theta))^2+(y-r\sin(\Psi) \sin(\theta))^2+(r\cos(\theta))^2}}\,dr\,d\Psi\,d\theta
\end{align*}
for all $(x,y)\in L$.
How can we show that $\phi$ is a constant or not on $L?$ It's better if  numerical approximations can be found for maximum and minimum of the function $\phi$ on $L$.

The following may be useful:

$$\frac{d\phi}{d\alpha}=\iiint\frac{\cos^2(\Psi) \sin^2(\theta) \sin(\Psi-\alpha)}{r [{4+r^2-4r\sin(\theta)\cos (\Psi-\alpha)}]^{3/2}}\,dr\,d\Psi\,d\theta$$
when $(x,y)=(2\cos(\alpha),2\sin(\alpha))$

Comment: $V$ is the function $\phi$?

Comment: Yes, there was a typo. Now I corrected it

Comment: Hint: Define $\alpha(t)=(2\cos t,2\sin t)$, thus $L=\alpha([0,2\pi])$. Prove that $\phi(\alpha(t))$ is constant. You can derivate.

Comment: It's hard to evaluate the integral after differentiating (Analytically)

Comment: Do you tried to use spherical coordinates to simplify the integrand expression?

Comment: I mean, the integrand is already in spherical coordinates.

Comment: Yes, I got the equation in polar coordinates because the integrating domain can be easily written in polar coordinates.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found used numerical approximations at some points on $L$ using Mathematica numerical integrals to show that $d\phi/d\alpha\neq0$. Seems like difficult to use a analytical method. (Not a proof)

```
    f[x_, y_, z_] := 
 NIntegrate[5*Cos[t]^2*Sin[T]/(r^2*Sqrt[(x - r*Sin[T]*Cos[t])^2 + (y -r*Sin[T]*Sin[t])^2 + (z - r*Cos[T])^2]), {r, 1, 2}, {t, 0, 2*Pi}, {T, 0, Pi}]
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it is hard to solve this analytically. Try numerical methods. You can evaluate the integral numerically at different points using Mathematica or MATLAB

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.